# Validate entire column with condition

Tags: custom-list, validation, calculated-column-formula

I have a list that has a column which is an integer. Is it possible when selecting a number to validate if this number has already been chosen in the list.

For example

List

Title         Order

Item1 1

Item2 2

I create a new list item, select '2' for the Order item, and SharePoint kicks back saying 'Please select an Order number which does not exist'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in the column settings on the list mark the field with "Enforce unique values", that way each entry must be unique!

[image]

More, and the above image: http://adicodes.com/column-validations-and-list-validations-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: The list has a couple of folders in it. Is it possible to make it unique per folder?

Comment: No it is not, not without attaching some form of workflow or EventReceiver